# LSH on android studio

Tags: java, lsh

Hi I am trying to make an android app for determining similarity images and my model uses lsh so how can I implement this using java on an android studio.

Comment: Hi, sincerely suggest you  to read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The quick fix to these kind of python dependent projects [guessing you are trying to implement this after developing with python] is simply to make them web services.

The other and some how convenient solution is to use the native implementations of MinHashLSh in Java, good-luck :)